# How to fix Material UI responsiveness

Tags: css, material-ui

How I can fix overflow [u can see overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58cx3.png) (in the second image you can see the reason) [second image reason text overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWW7J.png)

I am trying to fix my UI and using React and `Material UI` when checking the mobile version there is an overflow text(Material UI used span for that) and there is [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK5Or.jpg)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your text

```
  sx={{ 
    width: 250,
    wordWrap: "break-word"
  }}
```

Comment: It is worked thanks